# How to solve exponential equations like $2^x+x=5$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transcendental-equations

I tried the following:

Let $y=5-x$. Then, $2^{5-y}=y \implies y \cdot 2^y=32$

Taking the log of both sides yields
$$\log_2 y + y = 5$$

And that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(2^x+x\right)=\log(2)\,2^x+1\gt0$, or if it is assumed that $2^x$ is monotonically increasing, we have that $2^x+x$ is monotonically increasing for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $2^1+1=3$ and $2^2+2=6$, we see that the $x$ which satisfies $2^x+x=5$ is between $1$ and $2$. However, there is no solution in terms of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

However, if you are willing to use special functions like [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):
$$\newcommand{\W}{\operatorname{W}}
2^x+x=5\\
e^{x\log(2)}=5-x\\
32\log(2)\,e^{-(5-x)\log(2)}=(5-x)\log(2)\\
32\log(2)=(5-x)\log(2)e^{(5-x)\log(2)}\\
\W(32\log(2))=(5-x)\log(2)\\
x=5-\frac{\W(32\log(2))}{\log(2)}
$$
Approximately, $x\doteq1.7156207332755861694$.

Comment: You don't really need calculus to know that function is increasing.

Comment: @EthanBolker: good point, I have amended the introduction

Comment: @EthanBolker I don't know exactly what your definition of calculus includes or excludes, but if you're not willing to prove or assume the continuity of $2^x,$ or expand in series a la Euler, I wonder how else to *prove* that $2^x$ increases as $x$ increases.

Comment: @Allawonder A question like this tagged algebra=precalculus does not call for an answer that depends on a formal definition of exponentiation. You'd need one of those and a lot more to provide an unnecessary (at this level) rigorous answer.

Comment: @EthanBolker I grant that the tag excludes calculus. But I do not grant that the *content* of the post can be satisfactorily answered without calculus (well, supposing you include continuity and approximation as part of calculus). In any case I was just curious about the statement you made that we don't really *need* calculus to know that the function is increasing. That implies you have a way to know other than calculus; I was asking for such an explanation.

Comment: @Allawonder What determines whether or not an answer is "satisfactory" is context dependent, not mathematics. Is an answer using continuity or calculus satisfactory/rigorous if you haven't formally developed the real numbers? Do you need ZFC to do that? Sufficient unto the day is the rigor thereof, (My last words in this interchange.)

Comment: @EthanBolker In my last statement above, I pointed out that the main thing I was curious about is the non-calculus way you have, which can make us see that $2^x$ increases with $x.$ Either you have forgotten to supply this, or you have deliberately ducked the question. I won't guess which, but I have never seen a way to show that $a^x$ (with $a>1$) increases with $x$ without at least assuming or proving continuity.

Answer (score 5):

You are stuck for good reason. That equation does not have an algebraic solution. SInce $2^x + x$ is an increasing function of $x$ there will be a unique value of $x$ that makes it $5$. You can calculate it numerically as accurately as you like.

Answer (score 2):

Without using Lambert function (which I am in love with !), you can approximate the function building around $x=2$ (which would be the solution of $2^x+x=6$) the simplest $[1,1]$ [Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) of 
$$f(x)=2^x+x-5$$ This would give
$$2^x+x-5 \approx \frac{1+\frac{ 1+8 \log (2)+14 \log ^2(2)}{1+4 \log
   (2)}(x-2)}{1-\frac{2  \log ^2(2)}{1+4 \log (2)}(x-2)}$$ Then
$$x\approx \frac{1+28 \log ^2(2)+12 \log (2)}{1+14 \log ^2(2)+8 \log (2)}\approx 1.71574$$ Better would be the result using instead the $[1,n]$ approximant and  get an approximation still at the price of a linear equation. For example, the next one would give
$$x\approx \frac{3+292 \log ^3(2)+222 \log ^2(2)+48 \log (2)}{3+146 \log ^3(2)+132 \log
   ^2(2)+36 \log (2)}\approx 1.71560$$

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** The inverse of $f\left(x\right)=xe^x,f:\mathbb{R}\cap\left[-1,\infty\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cap\left[-\frac{1}{e},\infty\right)$ is $W\left(x\right)$, which is what is called the *product logarithm* function

Do not expect $x$ to have any kind of closed-form solution in terms of elementary functions, as $W\left(x\right)$ is not an elementary function itself. In fact, the inverse of $g\left(x\right)=x+2^x,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $g^{-1}\left(x\right)=x-\frac{W\left(2^x\log 2\right)}{\log 2}$.

So in your case, $x+2^x=5$, we have infinitely many solutions, $x\in\left\{5-\frac{W_{n}\left(32\log 2\right)}{2}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$, where $W_{n}\left(x\right)$ is the analytic continuation of the product logarithm function. And as someone below me noted, there is only one branch of the product log function for nonnegative real numbers so you have only one real solution. All of the other solutions are complex numbers.

Comment: It might be useful to point out that there is only one real branch of W for positive arguments.